# Cannot GET /app on VPS(works on localhost on mac)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, nginx, server

recently I created an app with name **app.js** and a side folder named **routes** that contains a **routes.js** file,
my **app.js** file has following code:

```
"use strict"; 
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var routes = require("./routes/routes.js")(app);


var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);

});
```

and my routes/routes.js file has code like below:

```
"use strict"; 
var afterLoad = require('after-load');
var http = require('http');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var utf8 = require('utf8');
var youtubeSearch = require('youtube-search');
var fs = require('fs');
var youtubeDl = require('youtube-dl');
var ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

var appRouter = function (app) {

    app.get("./", function (req, res) {
        res.send("Hello World");
    });
}

module.exports = appRouter;
```

I was set my **nginx** proxy pass like this :

```
location /app {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
```

but when I `pm2 start app.js` and  send a **GET** request to my server on link: **https://myserver.com/app** ,I give following error:

```
Cannot GET /app
```

note that when I use all of this system on my local server on Mac it's ok and there is no problem with this

Comment: Have you tried using `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/app/;` instead?

Comment: @SunilD. no,but of curse this is not the true solution, because / app is location of server not localhost

Comment: But the route in your routes file is defined as "/"? If you read the docs for [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) it kind of sounds like you want to add the "app" to the end of the proxy_pass value... but configuring is nginx always confusing for me. Just wanted to point out that it behaves differently when you do that, and it sounded like it's what you needed :D